# How to save each plot with color bar individually?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I am looping through a folder and performing image analysis on the images in a folder.  When I save these images the colorbar (or legend) is preserved from the previous loop and attached to the next image in the loop.

```
if file.endswith('.tif'):
    img_file = os.path.join(file_path, file)
    img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    roi1 = img[740:870, 730:835]
    plt.imshow(roi1)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig('roi1'+file)
```

The first image looks good:

[image: First image]

The subsequent images keep adding previous colorbars:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not clearing your previous plot. Just saving and showing it. The object itself remains. Add `plt.clf()` to the beginning/end of your loop.

```
if file.endswith('.tif'):
    plt.clf()
    img_file = os.path.join(file_path, file)
    img = cv2.imread(img_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    roi1 = img[740:870, 730:835]
    plt.imshow(roi1)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.savefig('roi1'+file)
```